# contar la cantidad de elementos que contiene un request laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy intentando contar la cantidad de datos que trae mi Request pero me devuelve el valor 1, cuando en realidad contiene 6 datos.

```
    public function Guardar(Request $request)
{
    echo count($request);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, tal vez la más sencilla es con el método all(), que normalmente lista los atributos enviados:

```
count($request->all());
```